# Timestamp value from pcap file (django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pcap

I am using django framework & trying to fetch Timestamp value from a pcap file.

I am unpacking bits like:

```
unpacked = struct.unpack ( '@ I H H i I I I I I I I' , raw_data[:40] )
timestamp = time.strftime ( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' , time.localtime ( unpacked ) )
```

but getting error for 'timestamp'

> Error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Full code is here: https://github.com/manishkk/pcap-parser/blob/master/webapp/views.py

Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) returns a tuple.

[`time.localtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime) takes an integer argument.

Hence:

> Error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Comment: What about time.strftime ()

Comment: @ManishKumar: `strftime()` takes a tuple, so if `unpacked` is in the right format you can use it directly (without calling `localtime()`). That format is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time). If not you will have to put it in the right format. I don't know anything about pcap so I can't help you there.

Comment: if I am not using it will give error for time.localtime-                          Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: function takes exactly 9 arguments (11 given)